Graph API to filter by multi-choice person column (SharePoint)?
How to filter by a multi-choice person column's Email (SharePoint)?
I tried this format by referring to Graph filter method, and it's not working
&$filter=fields/RequestorDetails/any(x:x eq 'name2@mail.com')

Example: With the below API URL
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{site-id}/lists/{list-id}/items?expand=fields($select=Id,RequestorDetails)

I get the below result and here RequestorDetails is a multi-choice person column (SharePoint)
{
  "value": [
          "fields": {
                      "Id": 1,
                      "RequestorDetails": [
                                            {
                                                "LookupId": 111,
                                                "LookupValue": "Name1",
                                                "Email": "name1@mail.com"
                                            },
                                            {
                                                "LookupId": 112,
                                                "LookupValue": "Name2",
                                                "Email": "name2@mail.com"
                                            },
                                            {
                                                "LookupId": 113,
                                                "LookupValue": "Name3",
                                                "Email": "name3@mail.com"
                                            },
                                            {
                                                "LookupId": 114,
                                                "LookupValue": "Name4",
                                                "Email": "name4@mail.com"
                                            },                    
                      ]
          },
          "fields": {
                      "Id": 2,                      
                      "RequestorDetails": [
                                            {
                                                "LookupId": 115,
                                                "LookupValue": "Name5",
                                                "Email": "name5@mail.com"
                                            },
                                            {
                                                "LookupId": 116,
                                                "LookupValue": "Name6",
                                                "Email": "name5@mail.com"
                                            }                    
                      ]
          }          
  ]
}

